# How to parse Json data with object class from url using AQuery

Tags: android, json, aquery

This is my code and I am having error to parse data from object, what changes can be done so as to parse data...

```
     aQuery.ajax(fetch_url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject obj, AjaxStatus status){
            super.callback(url, obj, status);
            Log.i("response", url + "response:" + obj);

            ArrayList<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("org_list");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
                    info.id = object.getString("Id");
                    info.servicename = object.getString("name");
                    info.amount = object.getString("amount");
                    list.add(info);
    });

}
```

And this is my JSON data format

```
{
  "org_list": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "name": "CBC-Test",
      "amount": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

When i edit from the below code and now i am facing null response value. I have also attached my logcat image file for further more details about my problem:[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdhso.jpg)

[Click here for further more details in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qytE.jpg)

[Logcat View1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPV0S.jpg)

[Logcat View2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovt0V.jpg)

Comment: post your error to

Comment: Please specify your problem

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as below,

```
aQuery.ajax(fetch_url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONObject obj, AjaxStatus status) {
        super.callback(url, obj, status);
        Log.i("response", url + "response:" + obj);

        ArrayList<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();


        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("org_list");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
                info.id = object.getString("Id");
                info.servicename = object.getString("name");
                info.amount = object.getString("amount");
                list.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

No need to re-create object of `JsonObject`. Just use that from response.

Comment: I copy this and edit in my code; its not happening! Yes, your code let me to remove red lines but the data is not parsing, it is showing null response in logcat.

Comment: r u getting something in `obj`..?

Comment: you mean to say in logcat... no i am getting nothing in there.

Comment: so, problem is in calling web service. B'cos you r getting nothing in response.

Comment: ya i also think the same but when i hit that url in postman it shows the data and i also checked the getString value name, they have same name as it is in json data. I am totally confused... Do we have something missing in code?

Comment: r u sure there is no errors in logcat?? and I hope you have given internet permission.

Comment: sir i have attached my logcat image file in my question, you can view over there if I did not understand...

Comment: Please review your code again. B'cos as per our conversation, problem should be in url / parameters / authorization / permission. I cannot help you further

Comment: Before this problem, I had checked parsing data and it works when i have json data in array class, but when i just bound my same data by object class it is not working now; as I show you my code and json data. I have checked Internet Permission. My same code is fetching data from another url that have array class and it is still working. Just to check whether it works or not in another activity, when it is bound by object then it generate such problems...

Comment: Ok sir I will check out that and I hope you had viewed my logcat errors. Thank you for your kind help sir!!

Comment: Would you excuse me for a while? Below try i use                                         " } catch (JSONException je) {
                        Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Error Parsing Data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }  "                    And in my activity it is showing this catch toast message. Do you any idea?

Comment: so what? I don't understand...r u getting any exception?

Comment: Ya I'm getting this exception. Do you know reason behind this exception?

Comment: If you have any idea in what case do this exception get occur then please share me, you would be so thankful... I am stucking with this problem...

Comment: I have edited my code. use that and share me your error logs.

Comment: I use your code still same message... I further edited my question by adding more images

Comment: Good to see, you found solution. But we should know which mistake we did. That's the **learning process for the Developers**. Never give up like this.

Comment: Sounds good, Yes I will try my best sir and Thanks a lot for being loyal with me and with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I searched my self and found a solution. But it is without using AQuery and it is by using RequestQueue...

```
    txtview = findViewById(R.id.showdata);
    Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.showbtn);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            jsonParse();
        }
    });
}
public void jsonParse(){

    String fetchurl = "http://use your url here.com/";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, fetchurl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("org_list");

                for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject patient = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String firstName = patient.getString("orga_organame");
                    txtview.append(firstName+","+"\n\n");

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```